# Unity Grid Layout Group with dynamic cells

Tags: c#, android, unity-game-engine

I am working on a shop for my app and I tried using a Grid Layout group for the items. My problem is that the cells in the grid do not dynamcially change their size, so it is a fixed size. How can i make them dynamic?

This is how it looks like right now:
[image]

and this is how it looks like when i change the resolution to for example 2560x1440:
[image]

As you can see the cells keep the same size and it does not look very good. I want the size of the cells to change so it fills up the space more but still stay at 2 rows.

Here some more Details:

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You need to change it manually using a script, there are 2 approaches.

1. Change the internal size of a cell and spacing
2. Change local scale.

Example of number 1:

```csharp
    Vector2 baseSize = new Vector2(800,600); // Base size of the screen
    Vector2 baseCellSize; // In editor Cell Size for GridLayoutComponent
    Vector2 baseCellSpacing; // In editor Cell Spacing for GridLayoutComponent
    GridLayoutGroup layoutGroup; //Component
    void Start()
    {
        layoutGroup = GetComponent<GridLayoutGroup>();
        baseCellSize = layoutGroup.cellSize;
        baseCellSpacing = layoutGroup.spacing;
    }
    
    void Update()
    {
        Vector2 screenSize = new Vector2(Screen.width, Screen.height); // Current screen size
        layoutGroup.cellSize = (screenSize / baseSize) * baseCellSize;
        layoutGroup.spacing = (screenSize / baseSize) * baseCellSpacing;
    }
```

Note that this does not keep the scaling right and items might get streched. In order to do that you need to commit to either scaling over width or height. Then you would create `screenSize` variable like so
`Vector2 screenSize = new Vector2(Screen.width, Screen.width);` note the Screen.width in both fields

**Edit:** you also might want to set content size fitter to unconstrained for both axis

Answer (score 0):

Is the canvas set to Scale with screen size?
Otherwise maybe it is a problem with the anchors in the content object. Try changing it to stretch. I have them in a panel which is set to stretch in both vertical and horizontal and it adapts when changing the resolution

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).